# How to insert mqsql database data into a scatter plot

Tags: html, scatter

I am trying to insert mysql database data into a scatter plot.
Previously, I was able to do this with the line graph, I tried to research but can't seems to find any video/link teaching this.

Please teach me on how can I send data into scatter plot.
I am aware that the code below is for line graph only.

```
<?php

    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbname='graph_plot';
    $dbuser='root';
    $dbpass='';
    
    try{
        
        $dbcon= new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
        $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
            die($ex->getMessage());
    }
    $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM graph_plot");
    $stmt->execute();
    $json=[];
    $json2=[];
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $json[]= $timestamp; 
            $json2[]= (float)$F1M;
    }
    /*echo json_encode($json);
    echo json_encode($json2);*/
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart js</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/graph_plot/index.php">
<button type="submit"?>Check for F1F</button>
</form>
<form action="http://localhost/graph_plot/drop.html">
<button type="submit"?>Home</button>
</form>


<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels:<?php echo json_encode($json);?>  ,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'F1M',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($json2);?>
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't catch exceptions if you do not know what to do with them! Remove try-catch

Comment: @Dharman by removing try-catch,  i received this error Notice: Undefined variable: dbcon in C:\xampp\htdocs\graph_plot\F1M.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\graph_plot\F1M.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\graph_plot\F1M.php on line 9

Comment: You have to keep what was within.